# Optimal PostgreSQL isolation level for multiprocessing app

Tags: django, postgresql, multiprocessing

I have an app that spins up multiple processes to read large amounts of data from several PostgreSQL tables to do number crunching, and then stores the results in separate tables.

When I tested this with just a single process, it was blazing fast and was using almost 100% CPU, but when I tried using 8 processes on an 8 core machine, all processes registered about 1% CPU and the whole task seemed to take even longer.

When I check `pg_stat_activity`, I saw several connections listed as "<IDLE> in transaction". Following some advice [here](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Idle+In+Transaction+Problem), I looked at `pg_locks`, and I'm seeing hundreds of "AccessShareLock" locks on the dozens of read-only tables. Based on the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html), I believe this is the default, but I think this is causing the processes to step on each others feet, negating any benefit to multi-processing.

Is there a more efficient isolation level to use, or better way to tune PostgreSQL to allow faster read-only access to several processes, so each doesn't need to lock the table? Specifically, I'm using Django as my ORM.

Comment: Better use another kind of storage. Postgres is optimized for transactional systems, which may be on the opposite side of your problem domain. How about HDF?

Comment: When you say "read-only tables", are you saying the tables are read-only to your app, or that they're read-only to *all* apps?

Comment: It is hard to tell what the bottleneck is, but AccessShareLock is certainly not it.  The "Idle in transaction" suggests the bottleneck is in your app, not in the database.  What are the top processes in 'top'?  Are they in IO wait?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what throttles your multiple cores, but it has nothing to do with the isolation level. Even if you have concurrent write operations. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/mvcc-intro.html)

> The main advantage of using the MVCC model of concurrency control
>   rather than locking is that in MVCC locks acquired for querying
>   (reading) data do not conflict with locks acquired for writing data,
>   and so **reading never blocks writing and writing never blocks reading**.
>   PostgreSQL maintains this guarantee even when providing the strictest
>   level of transaction isolation through the use of an innovative
>   Serializable Snapshot Isolation (SSI) level.

Bold emphasis mine.

Of course, reading also never blocks reading.

Maybe you need to reconfigure [resource allocation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.htmlallocated) on your server? Default configuration is regularly to conservative. On the other hand, some parameters should not be set too high in a multi-user environment. [`work_mem`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) comes to mind. Check the list for [Performance Optimization in the Postgres Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization).

And finally:

> Django as my ORM.

ORMs often try to stay platform-independent and fail to get the full potential out of a particular RDBMS. They are primitive crutches and don't play well with performance optimization.

Comment: Generally fair points, but I have to disagree on the last one. Django's ORM is anything but primitive or a crutch.